# Infinite loop while calling react setState in a second component

Tags: reactjs

I am working with 3 components that pass data to one another. On the second
component I am trying to do this when a flag passFlag is true.

```
     cancelCourse = () => {
            this.setState({
              settledAmount:'',
              creditAmount:'',
              productDescription:'',
              reasonCode:'',
              storedCollectedInformation:[]
            });
          }

          componentDidUpdate(){
            if(this.props.passFlag === true){
              this.cancelCourse();
            }
          }
```

I kept getting an infinite loop with the error message below.

invariant.js:42 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. 
This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or 
componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

How can I fix this please?

All I am trying to do is to reset the controls on a form to empty.

Comment: I am new to react. How can I fix this or write it in a better way?

Comment: When you issue `cancelCourse()`, you're calling `setState()` which will then call the lifecycle event `componentDidUpdate()` because the component's state has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the condition. something like this.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
   if(this.props.passFlag === true && this.props.passFlag != prevProps.passFlag){
    this.cancelCourse();
            }
          }
```

let me know if this worked

Comment: sorry i mistakenly submit without completing. you can check now. and let me know if it worked

Comment: This worked. Can you please explain this especially why it is different from my initial code?

Comment: yes actually what i did is i compared your current prop with  its previous state.  for example if passFlag  was false initially and then it turned true then only this condition will work. if there is no change in the prop then this condition will fail and you won't fall in a infinite loop.
Give me a up vote it i was helpful :)

Comment: This is beginning to work intermittently. It works once and the next time it does not work anymore. Any other idea?

Comment: can you tell me when and how is the passFlag changing to false ??? because according to condition if there is any change in props then only `this.cancelCourse()` will get triger.  so if this is not working then it means somewhere the condition is failing

Comment: Thanks. I had to reset passFlag to false and everything is back to normal now. I will continue to test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `componentDidUpdate()` here is that it calls `this.cancelCourse()`, which changes the state, and then it calls `componentDidUpdate()` again and the cycle repeats.

You could do something with `componentWillReceiveProps()`, if I understood what you are trying to correctly:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.passFlag !== this.props.passFlag) {
       this.cancelCourse();
  }
}
```

Be aware that `componentWillReceiveProps()` will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: If `componentWillReceiveProps()` will be deprecated, this isn't a valid solution. Provide a substitute...